# Count down days due from due date and past due

Tags: jquery, math

I am stepping through each class of .days-due to add a countdown number until the due date. EG: Due in 2 days - Due Date:2/8/2013

I also want it to show negative days past due date.

http://jsfiddle.net/infatti/XeqPT/#base

The days due number is wrong and I cannot understand why?

```
<ul>
<li>Due in <span class="days-due"></span> days - Due Date is <span class="month">02</span>/<span class="day">08</span>/<span class="year">2013</span></li>
<li>Due in <span class="days-due"></span> days - Due Date is <span class="month">02</span>/<span class="day">10</span>/<span class="year">2013</span></li>
</ul>

function daysUntil(year, month, day) {
  var now = new Date(),
      dateEnd = new Date(year, month - 1, day), // months are zero-based
      days = (dateEnd - now) / 1000/60/60/24;   // convert milliseconds to days

  return Math.round(days);
}

var monthDue = $(this).next('.month').text();
var dayDue = $(this).next('.day').text();
var yearDue = $(this).next('.year').text();

$('.days-due').each(function(){
    $(this).text(daysUntil(yearDue, monthDue, dayDue));
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$(this)` in your context refers to the `window`.

`next` looks at the siblings. Your spans are not siblings of window.

Change your selector. Also, your code is looking at only one set of elements but your markup has two.

Try this

```
function daysUntil(year, month, day) {
    var now = new Date(),
        dateEnd = new Date(year, month - 1, day); // months are zero-based
    days = (dateEnd - now) / 1000 / 60 / 60 / 24; // convert milliseconds to days
    return Math.round(days);
}

$("li").each(function () {

    var monthDue = $(this).find('.month').text();
    var dayDue = $(this).find('.day').text();
    var yearDue = $(this).find('.year').text();

    $(this).find(".days-due").text(daysUntil(yearDue, monthDue, dayDue));

});
```

Find all your `li` elements, and loop through them doing your calculation. Since we're selecting off `li` the context of `this` changes.

Comment: that fixes the days due number but it is not isolating each .days-due. It is returning the last result for all .days-due.

Comment: @simple, sorry, see update. You don't need to do `each` on the `.days-due`. Just find the child one.